# .htaccess rewrite with drupal and clean urls only partially works?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

Hey all, I am having an unusual access problem with Drupal running on a MAMP (Mac OSX, Apache, MySQL, Php) stack. The Drupal install is working fine, so I know it's not a Drupal issue. "Clean URLs" are working fine for anything with a single-level url, but nothing with 2+ path levels.

For example:

example.com/foo, example.com/bar, etc. All work perfectly.

example.com/foo/bar, example.com/bar/foo/bar, etc. Do **not** work.

I get an access denied (not 404) page, served by Drupal, with the login boxes and site name, but no theme applied. (and, yes, I am actively logged in as admin / user 1) ;)

If I disable 'clean urls' everything works perfectly. I am assuming this has something to do with my rewrite rules in my htaccess, but have searched the net to no avail (including drupal's site and irc channel).

My current .htaccess is as follows:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>


# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  # There is no end quote below, for compatibility with Apache 1.3.
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

# PHP 4, Apache 1.
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 4, Apache 2.
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # adapt and uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment and adapt the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# $Id: .htaccess,v 1.90.2.5 2010/02/02 07:25:22 dries Exp $
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, TE

Comment: For 403 responses issued by Drupal, there should be entries in the Drupal log showing the request for which the 403 was issued. This request will be the already rewritten version, not the initial clean URL. What do these entries say for your failing requests?

Comment: @Henrik - here is one of the 'access denied' entries from the drupal log:  Details / Type: access denied / Date: Thursday, September 23, 2010 - 15:52 / User: Anonymous / Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/settings/clean-urls / Referrer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/?q=admin/settings/clean-urls / Message: admin/settings/clean-urls / Severity: warning / Hostname: 127.0.0.1 / Operations

Answer (score 1):

You may have a busted RewriteBase, it sorta looks like you're trying to host the sites using a VirtualDocumentRoot but you're doing it with subdirectories instead of with subdomains. So if you want the site to be located at /foo or /bar then that RewriteBase needs to be /foo or /bar. Having it set to / only works if you can somehow use dns trickiness to direct to a domain or subdomain.

In our office we each have `site-folder.computer.fake-domain.com` and a dns server sitting in between us and the internet. So if I create a folder called foo I'll be able to access it at foo.computer.fake-domain.com/ instead of localhost/foo

Comment: Unfortunately my company will not give us access to the .hosts file so fancy dns trickery is probably not going to work for me. ;) But, yes, I think it might very well be a rewritebase issue - but I'm failing to see how to fix it. The base drupal files are in apache's doc-root, not in a subfolder of that root - in my case (for mamp stack) it is the htdocs folder (?)